# Generating Entity Classes from Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

How can I generate Entity classes directly from the database in Visual Studio 2010 (C#)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Entity Framework, LinqToSql or install a 3rd party solution like nHibernate.

There is no 'direct' way to do it without an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Open up an Entity Data Model using the Add Item dialog.  That'll give you a wizard for importing from a DB

Answer (score 0):

Use the handy wizard that is offered when you add an Entity Model to your project.